# Python subprocess ignores backslash in convert command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I want to resize multiple images using 'convert'.

This works great from the command line.

However, when I try to achieve the same from within Python3 using subprocess.Popen, the flag '\!' specifying that the aspect ratio of the image should be ignored during the resizing, does not work.

Starting from
[image: source]
I want
[image: source]
and not
[image: source]

From the command line this works fine using

```
convert source.png -resize 1230x80\! out_console.png
```

If I run this command from within Python3 using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen

cmd = [
    'convert',
    'source.png',
    '-resize',
    r'1230x80\!',       # Use '\!' ignoring the aspect ratio
    'out_subprocess.png',
    ]
proc = Popen(cmd)
proc.communicate()
```

the result is not resized:

[image: source]

I tried to escape the backslash character using `r'1230x80\!'` or `'1230x80\\!'` without success.

Comment: try just `'1230x80!'`

Comment: Why 'avoid like a plague' shell=True ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` needs to be escaped because you're running in a shell. But the command itself doesn't understand `\`, and `Popen` doesn't use the shell (unless you use `shell=True`, but avoid like the plague)

So you're just overdoing this.

Instead, pass arguments without quoting or escaping:

```
cmd = [
    'convert',
    'source.png',
    '-resize',
    '1230x80!',
    'out_subprocess.png',
    ]
```

now you have a portable command line that will even work on Windows (well, on windows there's a `convert` command which doesn't do the same thing at all so you'll have to specify full path of the `convert` command)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54581408/8935243):
The problem essentially is:

**Translate a shell command into a non-shell command.**

There is a [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) solving this task.

```
import shlex
shlex.split('convert source.png -resize 1230x80\! out_console.png')
```

gives

```
['convert', 'source.png', '-resize', '1230x80!', 'out_console.png']
```

Comment: Because I had a student do this literally earlier today: If you're incorporating user input in your command, don't just add it into the string then `shlex.split` it, because now user input with spaces or the like will cause a bad split. You can [fix that by putting all user input through `shlex.quote` first](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), but quoting a bunch of things just to format them into a string, then split the string is more complicated and error prone than just making it a `list` from the get-go.